# Issue saving 0.0 to cosmosdb double to int

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Using cosmosdb as storage I ran into an issue. I saved an object where one of the properties was set to 0.0 (tried both using double, decimal and float). When the value was later retrieved it was 0 and not with the precision 0.0. If I set it to something like 0.1 or 2.1 everything works as I would expect it to work.

Can someone explain why this is happening? For the usage of my data, I need it to be 0.0.

Best regards

Comment: I can imagine this just being an optimization, since `0 == 0.0`. It feels like you're trying to force formatting (probably for display purposes) into your datastore. If you _always_ format your data the way you want to show it, it doesn't matter if the value is 0, 0.0 or 0.3.

Comment: I see and get the point.

Comment: Could you post as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can imagine this being an optimization of CosmosDB, since `0 == 0.0` as far as the *value* goes.

It feels like you're trying to force formatting, probably for display purposes, into your data-store. If you always format your data the way you want to display it, it doesn't matter if the value is `0`, `0.0` or `0.316692`.